# How to narrow the redundancy of button and ListView Item in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an image button and a ListView.

For image button, I use any value of property Stretch, even UniformToFill, but the image does not cover the button.

For ListView, How to narrow top and button of listview item? I used wrap content property, but it affect nothing. My listview item just contain number, so does not need top and bottom  for other character such as y ô á ị.

Here is my current result

[image]

[image]

Here is my expectation

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is added as the button's content, so you can adjust the [padding property of the button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/alignment-margin-padding#margin-and-padding) to set the distance of the inner image from the border.

This image control is filled with `Stretch="Fill"`, and the width and height are consistent with the button.

```
<Button Padding="0,0" x:Name="btnTest"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Height="300">
    <Image Source="Assets/Test.png" Height="{Binding ElementName=btnTest, Path=Height}" 
           Width="{Binding ElementName=btnTest, Path=Width}" Stretch="Fill" />
</Button>
```

#### EDIT

The padding property of TextBlock cannot be set to a negative number, so you got an error.

I did a quick test and hope it meets your needs. I modified the Property of ListViewItem Style `Padding` to {0, 0} and set the `MinHeight` to 0.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{StaticResource SplitViewCompactPaneThemeLength}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

 <ListView Width="200">
       <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}" Background="Red" Content="2023/09/05 11：06" />
       <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}" Background="Red" Content="2023/09/05 11：06" />
       <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}" Background="Red" Content="2023/09/05 11：06" />
       <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}" Background="Red" Content="2023/09/05 11：06" />
       <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}" Background="Red" Content="2023/09/05 11：06" />
</ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!. And the ListView Item, How to narrow the TextBlock in ListView like the red image in my above question?. I tried to use padding="0,-5,0,-5" in TextBlock of DataTemplate of ListView. But there is a crash when running.

Comment: I modified my reply, hope it helps you. :)